# how to fetch the value of variable with function scope, outside the function i.e. to use the value in Global scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, local-variables

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('input-count');
var userInputValue;

userInput.addEventListener('change', inputFunction)

function inputFunction(e) {
    userInputValue = e.target.value;  //Want to Fetch value of userInputValue in console outside function

    window.newValue = userInputValue;

    var inputLimits = /^[0-9]+$/g;

    if (inputLimits.test(userInputValue) === false) {
        alertUser.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        alertUser.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
console.log(userInputValue);   //Not able to get the value...Kindly Help
```

Comment: `userInputValue` is not going to exist until after the first change event happens.

Comment: For what the value starts out as, just use `userInput.value` outside of the event handler